# When checking for file write permissions, what is the relation between FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY and using access control lists?

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, dos

For example, on the one hand, I can check

- if a file can be written to by building up a security identifier for a user,
- establishing a trustee,
- getting a discrete access control list and
- then getting the access mask
- finally checking if it contains the FILE_GENERIC_WRITE bit.

On the other hand I could just

- call GetFileAttributes and
- see if the returned value == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY

For the latter case if this attribute is set, I guess it means I don't have to bother with the ACL stuff. Or is there some other subtle point that I am missing?

Is it that the GetFileAttributes returns DOS information while the access control list function is newer windows api? Should I be checking for both?

Cheers,

Ben.

Comment: The best way to tell if you can write to a file is to write to the file and see if you get an error.  Anything you do to try to determine if a file is writable by you at this moment may be out-of-date information when you do actually try to write to the file.  And you'll never be able to anticipate how the rules may change for other filesystems and future versions of the OS.  Note, for example, that you didn't take the file sharing mode into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file attributes have no relation to ACLs.

You can have a "read only" file that you can have full permissions to, and non read only files that you have no access to at all.
You can also have non read only files with full access that you still can;t write to due to read only media.
Further more, the read only flag can also be removed by anyone with (write) access to the file.

The best way to see if you can write to a file is to try and write to it (or at least open it for writing).

Comment: Thanks. So if the file attribute is set to FILE_ATTRIOBUTE_READONLY but the ACL indicates full permissions, does that mean I can write to it? Trying to see if I can write to it is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: No, if the file is marked read-only, it doesn't matter what the ACL says.  You still can't write to it without removing the read-only attribute first.  Where the ACL comes into play is it determines if you can remove the read-only attribute.

Comment: @BenJ Everything needs to allow writing for writing to be allowed. If any one flag (ACL, attribute, media, etc) says it's read only, then it's read only.

Comment: Note - I am however rather perplexed as to why the powers that be decided that windows should bother with the attribute flag at all if the permissions can simply be stored in the ACL. It further seems strange that the ACL can indicate write access even if the attribute flag indicates that the file is read-only.

Comment: Because they predate ACLs and do still have their uses. I may want a file to be read only temporarily and don't want to have to mess with the security settings.

Comment: ... and the attribute flag is also a leftover from MSDOS.